# Downloading a file using the Dropbox Python library

Tags: python, dropbox

Environment: Windows 7, Python Tools for Visual Studio, Python 2.7, Python Package dropbox(6.9.0), Access Token from my Dropbox account

The following code is run:

```
    import dropbox
    access_token = '<token value here>'
    dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(access_token)

    with open("C:\Test.txt", "w") as f:
        metadata, res = dbx.files_download(path="/Test.txt")
        f.write(res.content)
```

It errors on the last line with the following:
  "No disassembly available"

I don't understand the error not being a Python developer.. the file is created on the local machine but nothing is downloaded into it from the dropbox file..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't looks like something relate to your code, but with Visual Studio, unfortunately I can't help you in that case. Anyway if you want to download the file you can try [`files_download_to_file`](http://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/moduledoc.html?#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_download_to_file)

Comment: just ran the code, worked like a charm, as Ceppo93 said the probable issue would be with your editor/debugger.

Comment: Thanks guys for the speedie and correct responses.. you were both spot on.. changed the breakpoint in the Visual Studio debugger and it worked just fine.. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

python code for dropbox download with business API:

```
def dropbox_file_download(access_token,dropbox_file_path,local_folder_name):
try:
    dropbox_file_name = dropbox_file_path.split('/')[-1]
    dropbox_file_path = '/'.join(dropbox_file_path.split('/')[:-1])
    dbx = dropbox.DropboxTeam(access_token)
    # get the team member id for common user
    members = dbx.team_members_list()
    for i in range(0,len(members.members)):
        if members.members[i].profile.name.display_name == logged_user_name:
            member_id = members.members[i].profile.team_member_id
            break
    # connect to dropbox with member id
    dbx = dropbox.DropboxTeam(access_token).as_user(member_id)
    # list all the files from the folder
    result = dbx.files_list_folder(dropbox_file_path, recursive=False)
    #  download given file from dropbox
    for entry in result.entries:
        if isinstance(entry, dropbox.files.FileMetadata):
            if entry.name == dropbox_file_name:
                dbx.files_download_to_file(local_folder_name+entry.name, entry.path_lower)
                return True
    return False
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import dropbox
access_token = '**********************'
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(access_token)
f = open("ABC.txt","w")                    
metadata,res = dbx.files_download("abc.txt")     //dropbox file path
f.write(res.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

To download a file using a token that refreshes automatically(`oauth2_refresh_token`):

```
import dropbox

def get_dropbox_client():
    return dropbox.Dropbox(
        app_key="YOUR KEY",
        app_secret="YOUR SECRET",
        oauth2_refresh_token="YOUR TOKEN"
    )


def download_file(remote_path: str, local_path: str):
    """
    Downloads a file at a `remote_path` in Dropbox 
    to a `local_path` on the local machine.
    """
    print(f"Dropbox: downloading {remote_path}")
    dbx = get_dropbox_client()
    dbx.files_download_to_file(local_path, remote_path)
    print(f"Dropbox: successfully downloaded to {local_path}")
```