# Using JSON in Header in Python Requests library

Tags: python-requests, dropbox-api

I want to make a request to an API which expects a JSON to be sent in the Header field. I'm unable to do it in Python Request library. 
I'm able to do it in cURL.

#### cURL code:

```
curl -v -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download
--header "Authorization: Bearer abcdefgh12343567"
--header "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\": \"/folder/file.mp4\"}" -o file.mp4
```

#### Python code:

```
import requests
import simplejson

r = requests.post(
        'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download', 
        headers={
            'Authorization':'Bearer abcdefgh12343567', 
            'Dropbox-API-arg': simplejson.dumps({'path': '/folder/file.mp4'})
})
```

Here the Header contains a JSON string.
I'm trying to use Dropbox's `files/download` API documented [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download).

Even though the request is sent, the JSON value seems to be wrong.

Comment: u look this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39984800/downloading-a-file-using-the-dropbox-python-library

Comment: Can you please include the status code you get?

Comment: Whenever a Dropbox API call fails, you will get some sort of error response. As Federico mentioned, check the status code. Also, check the response body itself, as it should contain a more useful/detailed error message. For `requests`, I believe you can do something like `print(r.text)`.

Comment: Thanks @Bryro, @Federico, @Greg. @Federico, @Greg When I posted the question, I received `HTTP 409` as the error code. On printing the content, it said that there was problem with the path. However, the above code seems to be correct and its working now. Not sure about what happened suddenly.

Comment: @Bryro Even dropbox itself seems to suggest using their SDKs instead of raw HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

The above code seems to work correctly now. I'm not sure about what happened - I was receiving `HTTP 409 error` earlier.

I was doubtful about how `Python Requests Library` would handle JSON string inside the header. So, I created an API to see how the server would read the headers made by both `cURL` and `Python Requests`. Both headers are identical.